# Doesn't ADL looks up static member functions?

Tags: c++, argument-dependent-lookup

This is follow up question from [Does argument dependent lookup only search namespaces or classes too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462474/does-argument-dependent-lookup-only-search-namespaces-or-classes-too) , In which @David Rodríguez said "ADL will look in the enclosing namespace of the type, and also **inside** the type itself" . I may have got him wrong what he tried to say but I was trying this example:

```
struct foo{
    static void bar(foo* z){}    
};

int main(){
    foo* z;
    bar(z);
}
```

It doesn't compiles, producing the error " ‘bar’ was not declared in this scope " . Is it the case that ADL doesn't considers the static member function?. I mean in the example associated class is `foo` so wouldn't ADL look inside the class? . Can anyone please simplify the rules here?

Comment: Bump...  the posted answer does not address the question of why ADL does not find `bar` in this code, it goes and talks about friend functions instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He probably meant this:

```
struct foo{
    friend void bar(foo* z){}    //not static, its friend now
};

foo* z;
bar(z); //fine now
```

But then technically `bar()` is not *inside* `foo`. It is *still* in the enclosing namespace of `foo`.

--

EDIT:

He indeed meant `friend`, as [he said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462474/does-argument-dependent-lookup-only-search-namespaces-or-classes-too) (emphasis mine):

> The best example is a **friend** function that is **defined inside** the type

And his example illustrates further. Probably you need to read "defined inside", rather than only "inside".

The word "defined" is all that makes the difference, because it *looks like* the function's *name* `bar` is introduced into the scope of the class, but in actuality, the name `bar` is introduced into the enclosing namespace of `foo` (see §3.3.1/3-4 and §11.3/6).

Here is a better example:

```
namespace Demo
{
     struct foo
     {
       friend void bar(foo* z){}
     };
}

foo *z;
bar(z); //foo (type of z) is inside Demo, so is bar
        //(even though bar is defined inside foo!)

bar(NULL);    //error - NULL doesn't help ADL.
bar(nullptr); //error - nullptr doesn't help ADL.

bar(static<foo*>(NULL)); //ok - ADL
```

Note that the name `bar`, even though is introduced into the namespace `Demo`, **is hidden**, and thus **cannot** be used from outside using usual name-lookup:

```
using namespace Demo; //brings ALL (visible) names from Demo to current scope

bar(NULL); //STILL error - means bar is invisible
```

Or,

```
Demo::bar(NULL);       //error - not found
Demo::foo::bar(NULL);  //error - not found
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But why ADL doesn't considers the static function inside the class, and ADL indeed considers the scope of class itself , isn't the case?

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: No. As I said, it is still in the enclosing namespace of `foo`. A friend function appears to be inside in the class. The name actually declared in the enclosing namespace scope.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation, I appreciate you answer, can you pls backup your statement with the support of statements quoted in c++ standard contradicting my example? . Thanks

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: Please read the section which talks about `friend` and ADL (I'm a bit busy so cannot loop it up myself). And also see the next example in my answer (which I added now).

Comment: @M3taSpl0it: *"P.S : your Big(O) of editing answer is way inefficient :P"*.. means?