# cannot access namespace scope friend explicitly

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, friend, argument-dependent-lookup, name-lookup

I had an issue today where ADL wasn't finding a static member function for a type defined inside a class.

That is, in the below example, `str(foo::Foo::Enum)` isn't located via ADL without explicitly scoping it, `foo::Foo::str(foo::Foo::Enum)`

```
namespace foo {

struct Foo
{
    enum Enum
    {
        FOO1,
        FOO2
    };

    static const char* str(Enum e);
};

}

foo::Foo::Enum e = foo::Foo::FOO1;
const char* s = str(e);              // ADL doesn't work
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725214/doesnt-adl-looks-up-static-member-functions) SO question, and as stated in the accepted answer, changing it to a `friend` function results in ADL now working.

```
namespace foo {

struct Foo
{
    enum Enum
    {
        FOO1,
        FOO2
    };

    friend const char* str(Enum e);  // note str is now a friend
};

}

foo::Foo::Enum e = foo::Foo::FOO1;
const char* s = str(e);              // ADL works now
```

Whilst this now helps ADL, I was surprised to find that I couldn't access `str` by scoping it with a namespace `foo`

```
foo::Foo::Enum e = foo::Foo::FOO1;
const char* s = foo::str(e);         // error: ‘str’ is not a member of ‘foo’
```

I ran a test, where I printed out the result of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, and was even more surprised to see that the scope of str is apparently `foo::`:

```
__PRETTY_FUNCTION__: const char* foo::str(foo::Foo::Enum)
```

**Working example below:**

```
#include <iostream>

namespace foo {

struct Foo
{
    enum Enum
    {
        FOO1,
        FOO2
    };

    friend const char* str(Enum e)
    {
        return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    }
};

}

int main()
{
    foo::Foo::Enum e = foo::Foo::FOO1;

    std::cout << str(e) << '\n';
    // std::cout << foo::str(e) << '\n'; // error: ‘str’ is not a member of ‘foo’

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
$ ./a.out
const char* foo::str(foo::Foo::Enum)
```

**Question:**

- Why am I unable to locate `str(..)` explicitly scoping it with the enclosing namespace?
- Why does `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` say it's in `foo::`, and yet I am unable to locate it as such?

Comment: There's a very big difference between the first and second example: In the first example the function `str` is still a *member of the class* `foo::Foo`, it's not a non-member function and can't be called as such. In the second example the `str` function *is* a non-member function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, but why can't I call `foo::str`, since `str` is a friend function in the `foo` namespace?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you'll notice I'm not trying to access `foo::Foo::str` (ie: as if it were a member), but instead I'm trying to access `foo::str` (ie: as if it were a function inside the `foo` namespace)

Comment: If you define a `friend` non-member function *inline* it is really scoped inside the class. That `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` doesn't say it is might be a problem with the compiler.

Comment: isn't the situation you ask is mentioned in the answer you just linked?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47136153/what-is-the-fully-qualified-name-of-a-friend-function-defined-inside-of-a-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Why am I unable to locate `str(..)` explicitly scoping it with the enclosing namespace?

From the standard, [[namespace.memdef]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.memdef#3)

> If a friend declaration in a non-local class first declares a class,
>   function, class template or function template the friend is a member
>   of the innermost enclosing namespace. The friend declaration does not
>   by itself make the name visible to unqualified lookup or qualified
>   lookup. [ Note: The name of the friend will be visible in its
>   namespace if a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope
>   (either before or after the class definition granting friendship).
>   — end note ]

That means `str` is not visible to name lookup; it can only be called via ADL.

> - Why does `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` say it's in `foo::`, and yet I am unable to locate it as such?

From [[class.friend]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#6),

> A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class ([class.local]), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.

`str` does become member of namespace `foo`; it's just invisible.

Explanations from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Namespaces):

> Names introduced by [friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) declarations within a non-local class X become members of the innermost enclosing namespace of X, but they do not become visible to [lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup) (neither unqualified nor qualified) unless a matching declaration is provided at namespace scope, either before or after the class definition. Such name may be found through [ADL](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) which considers both namespaces and classes.